# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL Database from GoDaddy Server

Tags: php, mysqli, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to a sql instance on google cloud from a website that is hosted on a godaddy server.

I am getting the following error

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (110)
```

I have authorized the IP to my godaddy server.

Here is how I am handling my connection...

```
<?php

    // Change this to your connection info.
    $DATABASE_HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    $DATABASE_USER = 'user';
    $DATABASE_PASS = 'pass';
    $DATABASE_NAME = 'db';
    // Try and connect using the info above.
    $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
        die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

?>
```

I have been STUCK for a little while and have not seen anything on the web to help.

Comment: if you would like to see the website it is otf.tdjdev1.com use test1@test.com in the email field.. thank you

Comment: It seems a firewall issue, are you sure that you authorized the external IP of your godaddy server in the connection section of your CSQL instance? You can see the Public IP of your server following [this tutorial](https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-my-server-ip-address-12071). Your code is correct and should work.

Comment: Your error message means that a firewall is blocking the connection. I recommend that you do not use IP based access and instead use SQL Proxy. This will make connections easier and increase your security. Unless you enable SSL for IP based access, your DB login and password are sent in the clear.

Comment: i am not sure why it is blocking it.. yes i have added the ip.. here is a link to a pic of the setting http://otf.tdjdev1.com/img/tdj.jpg 

@AlexRiquelme

Comment: @JohnHanley i will look into the sql proxy thing. i honestly do not even know what that means lol

Comment: @ToniDavisJ - Cloud SQL Proxy is a cool little piece of software written by Google that solves a lot of Cloud SQL connection and security problems. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you! i do not think i can use that on my shared godaddy server.. correct? I just saw a ton of commands and closed the window lol

Comment: @ToniDavisJ - I don't know. I don't use GoDaddy.

Comment: Is it possible that GoDaddy blocks this? Have you contacted their support?

Comment: @AndyShinn I did. was on the phone with the support guy for a little while trying to figure this out. I will try them again though